# Is there a way of using "native" Crystal to be determine if it's running in an interactive shell session?

Tags: crystal-lang

If a Crystal executable is running, what would be the recommended way of determining if it's running in an interactive environment?

For example:

```
`tty`.strip != "not a tty"
```

But, using native Crystal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [IO#tty?](https://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.24.1/io#tty?) method.

Compile a file (foo.cr) with the content:

```
puts STDIN.tty?
```

Run it from the shell:

```
./foo              # => true
echo "foo" | ./foo # => false
```